# Pyspark coding query: how to write more efficient code versus my groupByKey()?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am grouping some data in pyspark, similar to below:

```
data = [
    ("user1","2023-01-01","Sales", "item1"),
    ("user1","2023-01-02","Sales", "item2"),
    ("user3","2023-01-03","Mark", "item3"),
    ("user1","2023-01-01","Sales", "item2"),
    ("user2","2023-01-02","Sales", "item3"),
    ("user3","2023-01-01","Mark", "item1"),
    ("user1","2023-01-03","Sales", "item2"),
    ("user1","2023-01-01","Sales", "item1"),
    ("user1","2023-01-01","Sales", "item1"),
    ("user1","2023-01-02","Mark", "item2"),
    ("user2","2023-01-03","Sales", "item1"),
    ("user4","2023-01-01","Mark", "item2"),
    ("user1","2023-01-03","Sales", "item1"),
    ("user2","2023-01-02","Sales", "item1"),
    ("user4","2023-01-02","Mark", "item1"),
    ("user2","2023-01-01","Sales", "item2")
    
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema='User string, Date string, Dept string, Item string')
```

I want to group by the first three columns and aggregate the fourth into a list of strings:

```
df.rdd.map(lambda x: ((x.Date,x.User,x.Dept),x.Item)).groupByKey().mapValues(set).mapValues(list).toDF().show()
```

This produces the result required:

```
+--------------------+--------------+
|                  _1|            _2|
+--------------------+--------------+
|{2023-01-01, user...|[item2, item1]|
|{2023-01-02, user...|       [item2]|
|{2023-01-03, user...|       [item3]|
|{2023-01-02, user...|[item3, item1]|
|{2023-01-02, user...|       [item2]|
|{2023-01-01, user...|       [item2]|
|{2023-01-02, user...|       [item1]|
|{2023-01-01, user...|       [item2]|
|{2023-01-01, user...|       [item1]|
|{2023-01-03, user...|[item2, item1]|
|{2023-01-03, user...|       [item1]|
+--------------------+--------------+
```

However, I spent some time trying to use something more efficient that groupByKey - I tried reduceByKey...

I can't make anything else work. Suggestions for a better more efficient approach? Should I be bothering (it will be a very large dataset).

The use of 'set' is to make the lists unique. I edited to use distinct user groups per dept. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interesting approach is leveraging the Dataframe API directly instead of going down into the RDD.

For that, you need the following function

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list
```

And then use it in a simple aggregate sequence:

```
df.groupBy('User', 'Date', 'Dept').agg(collect_list('item')).show()
```

Giving the desired output that conserves the original column structure:

```
+-----+----------+-----+--------------------+
| User|      Date| Dept|  collect_list(item)|
+-----+----------+-----+--------------------+
|user1|2023-01-03|Sales|      [item1, item2]|
|user2|2023-01-01|Sales|             [item2]|
|user2|2023-01-03|Sales|             [item1]|
|user1|2023-01-01| Mark|             [item1]|
|user2|2023-01-03| Mark|             [item3]|
|user2|2023-01-02|Sales|             [item1]|
|user1|2023-01-01|Sales|[item1, item1, it...|
|user1|2023-01-02|Sales|      [item3, item2]|
|user1|2023-01-02| Mark|      [item1, item2]|
|user2|2023-01-01| Mark|             [item2]|
+-----+----------+-----+--------------------+
```

Also, in terms of efficiency, it's probably more efficient thanks to the API optimizations taking place on the back, which are generally better than user defined implementations.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, how would you go about having the final columns of lists contain unique non-repeated values?

Comment: Nevermind, I just noticed collect_set as I was looking up your collect_list example. Thanks